# How can I exclude data from list based on another array?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to exclude data from a list depending on whether the list contains one of the ID in another array?

For example, given:

```
int[] excludedCities = new int[] { 342, 344, 22, 19, 2 };
List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();
```

I want to remove the cities with the id in excludedCities array. Is there an easier way than iterating the list?

Comment: if you are using a `Set` object, then you can use set difference. if _A_ and _B_ are to sets, then _A - B_ (or _A \ B_, say _A drop B_) is all the elements in _A_ that are not in _B_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy removing the elements from the cities list then  you can do:

```
cities.RemoveAll(c => excludedCities.Contains(c.Id));
```

otherwise, you can do:

```
List<Cities> result = cities.Where(c => !excludedCities.Contains(c.Id))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually, I'd be very skeptical of using RemoveAll on a List<T>. Depending on the implementation, it may involve copying a large number of items around within the underlying array, which could choke on a large collection. In general, removing items from an array-backed list is to be avoided.

Comment: @glenebob why we even talking about performance here? the OP asked a rather straightforward question _I want to remove the cities with the id in excludedCities array._

Comment: @abdalrahmanmakahleh glad it worked, you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashSet<int> excludedCityHash = new HashSet<int>(excludedCities);
IEnumerable<City> filtered = cities.Where(city => !excludedCityHash.Contains(city.ID));
```

You can do just:

```
IEnumerable<City> filtered = cities.Where(city => !excludedCities.Contains(city.ID));
```

... but for more than a small handful of excluded cities, performance will start to suffer.

Comment: Or `cities.RemoveAll(city => excludedCities.Contains(city.ID));`

Comment: RemoveAll() is specific to List<T>, whereas Where() is a LINQ extension and therefore works on all IEnumerable<T> implementations. Also, Where() doesn't force you to materialize the result.